# Embedding the Lua shell into a Java Application (LuaJava)

Tags: java, shell, lua, luajava

I am working on a app, It has a GUI (But not Java swing and JFrame stuff) I want to incorporate the Lua shell into the GUI. LuaJava doesn't have good documentation (or atleast for me) on how to do this.

Comment: Please verify - so you want to embed a shell that users can type arbitrary Lua into and run, from within your Java application?

Comment: @Perception Yes, I want the interactive shell within my program. So users can do random stuff in LUA

Comment: Just a naming convention comment - Lua is typed Lua, not LUA, the same you write Java, not JAVA. Regarding the shell, just pass each line from a text control to `LuaState.doString` to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both LuaJ and Kahlua to do this. Works great with either one (they are roughly the same codebase) LuaJ has more complete implementations of the Lua standard libraries.

[image]

You can see on the right, I added an interactive Lua console to my IDE.

All my source is here: https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/wiki/Home

Actually, all you really need are the sources here:

https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/src/770c80f12c11/src/kahlua

Here is an example of exposing an API to Lua, and calling Lua functions from Java.

https://bitbucket.org/sylvanaar2/lua-for-idea/src/770c80f12c11/src/lang/documentor/KahluaPluginDocumentationProvider.java

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to write the 'shell' part yourself (in java), then pass the typed input to the embeded interpret (LuaJava, I suppose).

Maye [java-readline](http://java-readline.sourceforge.net/) could help.

Comment: Right, So what if I just parse the input to the Lua interpreter and then print out the result. So that its all handled across Java and Not a live terminal of the Lua shell?